# How to implement a double check lock that fully complies with the C++ standard and generally has no atomic instructions

Tags: c++, c++17

It started when I found a sentence in cppref:

"Note: usual implementations of this feature use variants of the double-checked locking pattern, which reduces runtime overhead for already-initialized local statics to a single non-atomic boolean comparison."

And then I tried to implement it myself without std::call_once.Then I realized that C++ didn't seem to be implemented in a completely standard way.This is my final version of the implementation, but actually relies on the concept of "memory ordering based on cache synchronization".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

template<typename T,auto = nullptr,size_t = 0>
class Static
{
    struct alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size) //To prevent the bool variable from being independently synchronized
        Releaser
    {
        union
        {
            char _place_holder{};
            T value;
        };
        bool constructed{};

        ~Releaser()
        {
            if (constructed)
            {
                value.~T();
            }
        }
    };
    inline static std::mutex s_m;
    inline static Releaser s_value;
public:
    static T &get()
    {
        if (s_value.constructed)
        {
            return s_value.value;
        }
        {
            std::lock_guard l(s_m);
            if (s_value.constructed)
            {
                return s_value.value;
            }
            new (&s_value.value) T();
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel);
            s_value.constructed = true;
        }
        return s_value.value;
    }
};


int main()
{
    auto& a = Static<std::string,main>::get();
    a = "1";
    std::cout << Static<std::string,main>::get();
}
```

I even doubt that this is true for most platforms.

I wonder if there is any implementation of pure standards without the need for ugly alignas and previous assumptions.

Comment: In general it's not necessarily possible to implement the c++ standard library in standard c++. The standard library implementation usually uses compiler specific tricks in its implementation

Comment: @AlanBirtles is right. In fact, a common justification for new C++ Standard Library features is "Can't be implemented efficiently in a third-party library".

Comment: @AlanBirtles But if I want to use a double-check lock on dynamic memory, and usually  do not need atomic instructions, this is not possible?

Comment: no, I didn't say its not possible, just that it doesn't have to be possible to implement a standard library feature in standard c++

Comment: You can use a relaxed atomic, which on all modern processors compiles to the same instruction as a non-atomic load or store, assuming the variable is suitably aligned.

Comment: @余国良 If you want to initialize dynamic objects, why can't you just use [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)? This is exactly what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is not correct because the initial test of `s_value.constructed` is performed without holding a lock. This means that one thread can read `s_value.constructed` while another thread (that *is* holding the lock) executes `s_value.constructed = true` at the same time. Because `s_value.constructed` is not an atomic variable, a simultaneous read and write results in a data race (which is undefined behaviour).

Any algorithm that uses atomic variables can be implemented without atomic variables. You simply replace each atomic variable `x` by the combination of a non-atomic variable `x` and a mutex `x_mutex` such that you only access `x` while `x_mutex` is held (*). Note, however, that this will defeat the purpose of double-checked locking, because now you *always* have to acquire a mutex. You might as well just get rid of the second mutex and always check the `constructed` flag while the first one is held.

The standard library provides implementations of mutexes and atomic variables because a user cannot implement these components themselves in a portable manner across all platforms. You should use the standard library mutexes and atomic variables instead of attempting to rewrite them.

(*) In rare cases where you need sequential consistency, you need to have a single mutex that guards *all* the concurrently accessed variables, rather than one per variable.